# Retrieve display names from Validator

Tags: c#, .net, validation, localization, attributes

I have a model class that uses `Display` and `RegularExpression` attributes, like the following:

```
public partial class User
{
    [Display(Name = "LOGIN_FIELD", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.General.User))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "MISSING_LOGIN", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.General.User))]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3,
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "LOGIN_LENGTH_ERROR", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.General.User))]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,40}$",
                       ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.General.User), ErrorMessageResourceName = "LOGIN_FORMAT_ERROR")]
    public string LOGIN { get; set; }
}
```

I later use `Validator.TryValidateObject` to find any errors in instances of this class:

```
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
            instance: usuario,
            validationContext: new ValidationContext(usuario,
                                                     serviceProvider: null,
                                                     items: null),
            validationResults: validationResults,
            validateAllProperties: true);
```

This way, I get the error messages correctly localized (`ValidationResult.ErrorMessage`), but the name of the offending field (`ValidationResult.MemberNames`) is just the field name (in this case, `LOGIN`), and not its string in the resources file.

I need to obtain a list of the localized error messages with the localized name of each member. What is the simplest way to do this? Can I specify to Validator how I want the names? Do I have to use reflection?

Comment: I have the same issue, Could you please share your solution?

Comment: Sorry, haven't touched C# in years. I think I pulled it off but wasn't satisfied with the results, or I would've posted it here.